# How do I format a number to have at least 5 digits in a file name with a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro which involves generating a filename and saving an excel sheet as pdf with that name.

I was able to generate target folder name as follows.

```
user_name = Environ$("UserName")
file_dir = "C:\Users\" & user_name & "\Documents\Jobs\"
```

The file name is created as follows.

```
Job_No = Site & "SV" & num_from_cell
PDF = Job_No & ".pdf"
file_path = file_dir & PDF
```

Currently the above code returns `MWSV234.pdf`. I want it to be `MWSV00234.pdf`. `num_from_cell` comes from one of the cells in Excel sheet.

In short, I want to left pad `num_from_cell` to 5 digits. Could you please tell me how?

Comment: `Job_No = Site & "SV" & Right("0000" & num_from_cell, 5)`

Answer (score 3):

It would be safer to use `Environ$("HomePath")` to get the users home directory rather than `Environ$("UserName")`

```
file_dir = Environ$("HomePath") & "\Documents\Jobs\"
```

---

Then use `Format` to format with leading zeros for 5 numbers

```
Job_No = Site & "SV" & Format(num_from_cell, "00000")
PDF = Job_No & ".pdf"
file_path = file_dir & PDF
```

Comment: `Environ$("HomePath")`  returns a single backslash at my (company) computer. I usually go for `Environ$("UserProfile")`